# Intel display controller unclaimed

Tags: 12.10, drivers, intel, bumblebee

I have just reinstalled Ubuntu 12.10 on my Optimus laptop with Intel Ivy Bridge and Nvidia 650M graphics cards. I have set up Bumblebee following this guide: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/use-nvidia-experimental-drivers-310.html
Optirun works, but when using the integrated graphics, I have a slew of issues which I think come from my intel display controller not loading the right driver. Among them are crashes when logging out, crashes when resuming from suspend, being unable to adjust screen brightness and my cursor being invisible when not moving. I have tried googling, but have been unable to solve the problem on my own. This is my lshw:

```
sudo lshw -c display
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

I think the Intel display controller was unclaimed before I installed Bumblebee, but I'm not completely sure. Additionally when I do lsmod, i915 (which I think should be the driver?) is not listed anywhere.

I have tried following the advice in post #9 here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1800447
in order to force the driver to load with modprobe. However, when I run `sudo service gdm stop`, I simply get `gdm: unrecognized service`

I am only a Linux user of a few months, so maybe I am missing something obvious here. I am very fuzzy on how X, GNOME, Unity and the driver system works.

EDIT: Okay, so apparently the VESA driver is loading instead of the intel driver. I found ot why `sudo service gdm stop` didn't work. Apparently the advice was outdated,so I tried with `sudo service lightdm stop` instead. This causes my screen to turn this weird pink-purple colour, and becomes unresponsive. In this state, I am unable to bring up a terminal by ctrl+alt+f1. I tried to restart lightdm blindly, but got no response. My only option was to press the power button, which seems to initiate shutdown. 
So, I think the question has become, how do I unload the VESA driver, and load the proper intel driver instead?